# How can I login to google drive using selenium & python WITHOUT Drive API

Tags: python, authentication, selenium-webdriver, oauth, automated-tests

So I am trying to login to google drive through web parsing, and it seems to not allow scripts to login to drive directly. Is there any possible way to overcome this **without using Drive API**. What might be the possible way(s) to do so ? Is there any way to hide from chrome the fact that I am using a script ?

```
from webbot import Browser

web = Browser()
#Go to google drive's Login
web.go_to('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=wise&passive=true&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2F%3Futm_source%3Dar&utm_medium=button&utm_campaign=web&utm_content=gotodrive&usp=gtd&ltmpl=drive&hl=en&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin')
web.click(id='identifierId')
web.type('EMAILID')
web.click('Next', tag='span')
web.click(id='password')
web.type('PASSWRD')
web.click('Next', tag='span')

exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

A more secure account wouldn't allow, but a less secure one just requires a bit of authorization after login

Comment: Also, to hide a scripts(partially), chrome can be run in debugging mode. :)